# App A launches App B then App A closes leaving App B open.in Android..how can this be achieved?

Tags: android, spawn

Searched for an answer on this and I cant find what I think is an answer to this specific issue. All seem to refer to Intents which remain "tied" back to the launching App.
So I want to start  App A
Hit a button on UI in App A that launches App B
When App B launches App A closes leaving App B running.

Any ideas..been going round in circles. Maybe it is just not possible.
Thanks for any help

Comment: App A and B both belongs to you? means both are your apps?

Comment: No App A is mine and App B is say the camera or a browser window. I know how to launch each of those through an Intent but I want to shut App A when App B is launched.

Comment: what is the use case? why you want to do that? if you are opening them as another application then they should be available in background when your app gets killed I believe